# Is Paradise the fruit of the worshipping in the world?

Tags: jannah, ibadah

Imam Rabbani states the following:

"The trees and rivers of Paradise do not resemble the ones in the world. What you find there are the fruits of the deeds of worshipping and good deeds in the world."

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sometime we struggle hard and play fairly but still we cannot get the same reward as we expecting .so he(Imam Rabbani) try to tell the people that you should still remain hopeful and just thought that one place (paradise)is specially made for you people where you would be rewarded with such reward which you never seen before.where you get the fruits which you never tested before because these fruits are very testy and also you see the rivers,there water is so sweet and you want to drinking continuously.so we should always be fair in our dealing so that we can enter in the paradise